# Instantiation of NSMutableArray in Obj-C 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is `NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` any more or less correct than `NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new];` in terms of style or efficiency?

Comment: The two are identical in function.  `new` is probably underused, mainly out of habit (and a little bit of fear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually both are used to initialize the new object. new will also do **allocate** and **initialize**. But the apple recommends that call **alloc** first, then after invoke the **init** method. Thats why we  are using `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`

Anyway, there is no big difference here

Comment: Even if you are using `new`. `alloc` will do first then only initialize it. In fact both are same

Answer (score 0):

Neither is "more correct," and in fact they are functionally equivalent, but `alloc` is much more common than `new` since custom initialization is always done through `initWith...`-style methods. So it's hard to say something is stylistically *correct*, but `new` is certainly less stylistically *standard* in modern Objective-C.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Modern objective C prefers `new` unless if you are not supposed to any custom initialisers like `initWith..`

Comment: Actually Apple said on last years WWDC or the year before that `new` is a deprecated style. New classes hardly ever have a `new` method, Apple highly discourages you to offer them in your own classes and they even gave a technical reason why one shouldn't use them, but I cannot remember what it was.

Comment: @Mecki: It's definitely true that `new` is the old style. `new` is how it used to be done back when Objective-C leaned more in the Smalltalk direction. But it's not *quite* true that "new classes hardly ever have a `new` method". They inherit NSObject's `new` just like all other classes do, which is equivalent to alloc+init. If you can write `[[SomeNSObjectSubclass alloc] init]`, you can write `[SomeNSObjectSubclass new]`. It's not marked as deprecated; it's just stylistically nonstandard.